# Initializing a large two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization

I want to initialize all elements of:

```
char buffer[1000][1000];
```

to `' '`.

I've tried

```
char buffer[1000][1000] = { ' ' };
```

and

```
char buffer[1000][1000] = { { ' ' } };
```

but both ways only seem to initialize only the first term.

I am willing to consider alternative approaches that get the job done, but I would prefer to avoid writing in this kind of initialization code in main, or even a separate initialization method.

Comment: `memset(buffer, ' ', sizeof buffer);`

Comment: So, first off, you are stack allocating `1000 * 1000 = 1,000,000` chars.  This is... bad.

Comment: It initializes the all terms, but with zeros.

Comment: He didn't say the array was on automatic storage.

Comment: Right about here, many people decide that using C++ (and `std::vector<char>(1000*1000, ' ');`) has some good points.

Comment: @wildplasser: Does he have to say it explicitly?  I can read code ya know, that's an array with automatic storage duration if I have ever seen one.

Comment: @EdS.: not if that's a file-scope declaration

Comment: I don't see it declared inside the body of a function. I don't even see a function. Maybe ya can read invisible code, too?

Comment: @Christoph, wildplasser: Good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
memset(buffer, ' ', sizeof buffer);
```

If the array has automatic storage duration, consider heap-allocation to avoid overflowing the stack.

If the array has static storage duration, you'll still need to initialize the array at runtime as there's no way to initialize elements with a non-zero value without providing a separate initialization value for each of them.

Answer (score 3):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset

```
char *buffer = malloc(1000*1000);
memset(buffer, ' ', 1000*1000);
```

You'll want to test the return code of malloc and replace the literals, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: `malloc` without a cast should not produce a warning in C and it is actually bad to cast in the first place.

Comment: Indeed no, but I think memset will. It wants a size_t, doesn't it? (edit: I'm wrong, just tried it. Giving memset an int doesn't give a warning. Apologies, I'll edit my answer.)