# C Large Two Dimensional Array Creation

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

****New to C!****

I am running Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 on Windows 7 (64 bit build)
My computer has 39GB of Physical Memory.

I am trying to create a large two dimensional array. I have already created code that tells me how many dimensions it has, and how many items are in each dimension.

As an example, let's say the array is two dimensional: One million items long, and 6 wide:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
...and on to one million items.
```

I have tried:

```
float MyArray[1000000][6];
```

but this crashes Dev-C. It seems to fail when I try to initialize an array larger than:

```
float Myarray[86486][6];
```

I imagine I am experiencing a "stack overflow" which amuses me since that is the name of this site.

I have been digging around and it seems I need to use malloc to help C understand how much memory to reserve. I have seen good examples of how to use this to set up a 1 dimensional array, but **I would very much appreciate example code of how to set this up with a 2 dimensional array.**

I have seen the example here: [Initializing a large two dimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813882/initializing-a-large-two-dimensional-array-in-c)

But I'm afraid I am too much of a beginner in c to understand the brief explanation.
As background: I am coming from python where you can make an array of (almost) any size or dimension by just declaring MyArray=[] and then filling it with whatever you want.

Thank you!

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Comment: Try to use heap instead of the heap. I think that you are limited dimension for stack memory. Also, with gcc you resize space of this two types of memory.

Comment: Dev-C++ is _very_ outdated, there are many better IDE's out there you could use

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version of Dev-C++, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: @Orwell Thanks! I updated to your version of Dev-C++ and things in general are working faster and smoother. Although my C tutorial book is for the ANSI standard so the compiler yells at me a lot for being antiquated!

Comment: @Dlinet: (this is a sort of PM): the compilers shipping with Dev-C++ by default should fully support ANSI C. All you need to do is pass -ansi to the compiler. This can be done for non-project compilation using Tools >> Compiler Options >> Settings. For projects, please go to Project Options >> Compiler. You might also want to tell the compiler you're using by changing -std (2nd tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you're running up against the limit of the size of an individual stack frame.

Here's one approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
int main(void)
{
  /**
   * declare myArray as a *pointer* to a 6-element array of float
   */
  float (*myArray)[6];
  /**
   * dynamically allocate space for 1 million objects of type
   * "6-element array of float"
   */
  myArray = malloc(sizeof *myArray * 1000000);
  ...
  myArray[i][j] = ...;
}
```

Why this works:

The subscript operation `a[i]` is interpreted as `*(a + i)`; that is, we compute the address of the `i`'th element (**not byte**) after `a` (the base address of the array) and dereference it.  Since `myArray` is a pointer to a 6-element array of `float`, `myArray[i]` gives us the address of the `i`'th 6-element array of `float` after `myArray`.

The advantage of this approach is that the memory is allocated in a contiguous chunk, and you can subscript `myArray` like any 2-d array.

Comment: Is it the size of individual stack frame? I think it is the limit on the size of the whole stack.

Comment: @nhahtdh: TBH, I don't really know; I don't normally get down into the guts that deeply.  For some reason I thought it was a limitation on the individual frame that was the issue, but I admit I could be making that up.

Comment: Hmm, I am a little confused about the concept here. So on the line starting with float, you create one of the 6 item arrays. Now why can we call myarray[x][x]?

Comment: It's quite simple to test: Just allocate around 1MB on stack, and make the program recursion and print the number of recursion levels until it crash, compare to without 1MB allocation. You will see whether it is limit on whole stack or limit on individual stack frame. I believe it is the limit on whole stack.

Comment: @Dlinet: I'm creating a *pointer* to a 6-element array of `float`, not an array object.  I then assign the value returned from `malloc` to that pointer.  I'm basically allocating the space for the 100000x6 array dynamically on the heap, and setting the `myArray` pointer to point to it.